# Filter null predecessor

Tags: excel, rally

What is the syntax for the filter of the Excel Add-on for Rally?

I would like to filter out the rows (User Stories) that don't have a predecessor.

I tried (Predecessors != "null") but that doesn't work.

Regards,
Jim

Answer (score 0):

The Predecessors attribute on Stories in Rally is represented by a Collection (an Array of references to the Predecessor Stories). Unfortunately Collection attributes cannot be used in simple Webservices query syntax.

Unfortunately your best bet is to do the filtering in Excel by setting up a data filter that excludes rows where this field is empty.